# PHP string to array

Tags: php

I have a string that when I var_dump returns the following

```
string(20) "{\"key1\":\"key1_value",\"key2\":\"key2_value\"}"
```

How can I convert that into an array that will return the following when I var_dump?

```
array(2) { ["key1"]=>  string(20) "key1_value" ["key2"]=>  string(20) "key2_value" }
```

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a simple JSON array that got mangled by PHP's `magic_quotes` or some other escaping function. Turn off `magic_quotes` and run `json_decode()` on the string.

```
// If you cannot disable `magic_quotes` or you escaped it manually, use this
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($strings), true);
```

Comment: Thanks Sander, that works. I was just doing json_decode without the stripslases which was the issue. Also I actually needs to convert that into an array since what you recommended returned an StdObject. So actual code I used is (array) json_decode(stripslashes($strings));

Comment: Actually what David L.-Pratte recommends by setting second parameter to true in the json_decode works too. So json_decode(stripslashes($strings), true);

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course. I have edited my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 7):

What you have as data looks like valid JSON. You probably can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the second parameter to true (to get an associative array) like this:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
explode(',\\',$string);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: He needs `explode`.  `implode` turns an array into a string.